# Laravel and React Upload image via Storage Facades fail

Tags: laravel

I want to upload a logo for my reports.

This is a snippet from my `uploadLogo` function

```
$file = $request->file;
Storage::disk('logo')->put('logo.png', $file);
```

I've created a `logo` profile in `filesystems.php` like this.

```
    'logo' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/img',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

But it eventually created the file in a 'random' ( or misunderstood ) location with a random name.

```
public\img\logo.png\M4FGLpZzAsyxn8NHiJLxo95EoP7I3CkIWvqkiQsv.png
```

What am I missing in my setup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the file directly of the request's file (UploadedFile) object. And use `storeAs` to save by the name you supply. The `Storage::put` and UploadedFile::store` methods generate random names for the filed being stored.

```php
$path = $request->file->storeAs('img', 'logo.png', 'logo');
```

More info https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#storing-files and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: Does the same apply for laravel 7?

Comment: Yes. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files and https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#storing-files